# About registers and IMUL

Tags: computer-architecture, assembly

I do not know if this question makes sense
BUT

AX has two halves al and ah but the higher halves of EAX and RAX are not addressable.

When IMUL instruction is executed *e.g. IMUL r/m16* the os uses ax and dx registers:
*DX:AX = AX*r/m16*

This made me question why is using two registers necessary for this instruction and
Why accessing higher half of RAX or EAX without bit shifting not possible?

Would having eah:eal, rah:ral be meaningless?

Comment: This isn't really a CS question. The reasons are historical and practical. The IMUL r/m16 instruction was added to the x86 series long before EAX was. When they added EAX, they had to keep the old instruction for backward compatibility, and adding an instruction with the same functionality but a different output register wasn't worth the cost. Special instructions to access the top of EAX and RAX also weren't worth the cost since shifts are fast enough. (Shifts were much slower in the old days.)